# Any examples of wireless power or inductive power transfer in Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, technology

Is there any example of charging or powering devices using wireless electricity or inductive power transfer in Star Wars? Is everything that receives power still done by plugging in wires?

Comment: There is [this](http://i50.tinypic.com/59uffb.jpg)

Comment: @amflare I don't see any image at that URL. Please use StackExchange's own image hosting, not an external hosting service.

Comment: Does using The Force count?

Comment: Are there any examples for the opposite? There are outlets, but is anything ever charged or powered by them? Does Luke ever charge his sword for example in the movies?  As far as I remember, Star Wars is rather superficial on how stuff is wired/wirelessed and focuses more on story elements such as Luke becoming a Jedi. It very well might be that someone plugs something in, but maybe it would be nice to establish that first

Comment: There was that time when Emperor Palpatine transferred electrical power to Luke Skywalker with lightning bolts.

Answer (score 1):

It's a game mechanic, so its canonicity is arguable, but in [*Jedi: Survivor*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Jedi:_Survivor), there are locked chests that can only be opened by powering a nearby conduit. The chests appear to have some sort of electricity-receiving antenna that starts rotating after the conduit is powered, allowing the chest to be opened:

Answer (score -3):

I'm not totally sure what you mean by wireless. In New Hope, C-3PO had a thumb-sized communicator which was used when Luke and the others were in the trash bin on the Death Star.  Darth Maul had a similar device in Phantom Menace. If you meant something that flies, there was a solar sail shop in that one too.

Comment: I don't think the OP means these.  He's asking about things like phone pads.  Things that will charge a device without having to plug it in.